# Reference request: translate-containment quasiorder on a double coset space

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

[A Groupprops page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Double_coset_of_a_pair_of_subgroups) introduces a quasiorder on the double coset $H \backslash G / K$ for $H,K\le G$: $HxK \preceq HyK$ iff there exists $g, h \in G$ s.t. $gHxKh \subseteq HyK$.

I have an inkling that this notion may be useful for a problem that I'm thinking about, and I would like to learn more about it (e.g., when is it a partial order?).  But the terms used on the page appear nonstandard, and I can't find a resource myself.

What's a good source from which to learn about this preorder?

Comment: @vipul Are you still active here?